# Picture of spec?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I recall seeing a hand-drawn picture of spec of a ring (maybe of $\mathbb Z$?) that had been passed around in the early days of the Zariski topology.  Does anyone know where I can find a copy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you mean [this image](https://pbelmans.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/a-latex-version-of-mumfords-impression-of-spec-zx-or-some-tikz-tricks/) by Mumford.

[image: spec Z[x] by Mumford]

Comment: More informative link at the same site:  http://www.neverendingbooks.org/index.php/mumfords-treasure-map.html   .  This contains the essay on "Mumford's treasure map" cited in the other answer.

Comment: The link in the previous comment is dead, here's [a new link](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/mumfords-treasure-map) from the same web site.

Answer (score 7):

You are thinking of the picture of Spec($Z[X]$) in Mumford's Red Book of Varieties and Schemes.   A reproduction is downloadable at the link posted in the other answer, and other (less famous) pictures of prime spectra appear in the Eisenbud and Harris introductory book on schemes.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure not to miss this very interesting paper (in English) on "Mumford's treasure map" and related concepts: Lieven Le Bruyn: [Un dessins d'enfants](http://matrix.cmi.ua.ac.be/DATA2/Alev60.pdf)