# Looking at evaluating polynomials at a point via schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $R$ be some commutative ring with identity and fix some $a \in R$. Then, consider the evaluation map:
$$\epsilon_a: R[x] \to R: f(x) \mapsto f(a)$$
We know that this is a surjective homomorphism (in fact, it gives the isomorphism $R[x]/(x-a) \cong R$), so it gives us a closed subscheme $\text{Spec} R \to \mathbb{A}^1_R$. My question is then: is there a geometric way to imagine this closed embedding of scheme, particularly in regards to the process of evaluating of polynomial $f(x)$ at $a$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. Maybe some examples will help. Take $R = k$ a field; then $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec} \Spec(k)$ consists of a single point (the zero ideal), and the embedding is just the map sending this point to the ideal $(x - a) \in \Spec(R[x])$. What happens if you take $R = k[y]$, so you have a mapping $R[x,y] \to R[y]$? There is also a famous picture of Mumford depicting the case $R = \mathbb{Z}$, which you can find [here](https://pbelmans.ncag.info/blog/atlas/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8840).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S:=\operatorname {Spec}R$ and let $\pi:\mathbb A^1_R\to S$ be the canonical projection, dual to the embedding of rings $R\to R[x]$.
The fiber of  $\mathfrak p\in S$ under $\pi$ is the affine line $\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)=\mathbb A^1_{\kappa (\mathfrak p)}$ over the residue field $\kappa (\mathfrak p)=\operatorname {Frac}(R/\mathfrak p)$.
So the geometric picture is clear: the scheme  $\mathbb A^1_R$ is obtained by gluing together the affine lines over $\kappa (\mathfrak p)$ where $\mathfrak p$ runs through $S$.
And what is the morphism $j_a:S\to \mathbb A^1_R$ dual to your evaluation $\epsilon_a:R[x]\to R$ ?
It is the map $j_a:S\to \mathbb A^1_R$ associating to the prime ideal $\mathfrak p\in S$ the prime ideal $j_a(\mathfrak p) \subset R[x]$ consisting of the set of polynomials  $f\in R[x]$ such that $f(a)\in \frak p$.
The point $j_a(\mathfrak p)$ can also be seen as the rational point $\langle x-\bar a\rangle \in \mathbb A^1_{\kappa (\mathfrak p)}=\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$,where $\bar a \in \kappa (\mathfrak p)$ is the image of $a$ under the natural map $R\to \kappa (\mathfrak p)=\operatorname {Frac}(R/\mathfrak p)$.